# How ReadyAPI uses swagger file. Provide steps how that swagger file is connected with ReadyAPI

Tags: swagger, ready-api

We want to know how the Ready API integrated with swagger, Please help us on the same.

Comment: What did you already find out? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

ReadyAPI is integrated with SwaggerHub, not Swagger.

The Swaggerhub integration creates a connection between an existing Swaggerhub account and ReadyAPI. Once an account has been connected all APIs available to that Swaggerhub account are accessible in ReadyAPI.

ReadyAPI doesn't have an integration with the open source version of Swagger, but you can still work with Swagger/OpenAPI definitions in ReadyAPI.

Documentation for the Swaggerhub integration is found [here](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/integrations/swagger.html).

Comment: In my experience, many people still use the Swagger name for OpenAPI specifications.